# UITableView with beginUpdates() bounces

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I use the typical combination CoreData - `NSFetchedResultsController` - `UITableViewController`.
When I use :

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
  self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
  self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

By updating one item in the Data Source (no insert nor delete), sometimes, the tableView bounces up and down for no reason.

If I have a few cells, not enough to fill the tableview, it doesn't bounce.

if I have much more cells to scroll the tableview, it doesn't bounce.

However, if I have just enough cells to fill the tableview, this is where it bounces.

If I remove `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`, there is no random bounces, however I loose the advantages of begin/endUpdates().

> A preview can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yP7f8_efM-E) or [over here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/11m5xhn2835rvt1/buggy-iphone.mov)

What could cause that ? And how to fix it ?

Comment: you are calling tableView.reloadData() somewhere which is causing this issue

Comment: set `tableView.bounces = false`

Comment: I'm not calling `tableView.reloadData()` anywhere.

Comment: `tableView.bounces = false` doesn't fix it.

Comment: I've tried this, it doesn't work, still bouncing.

Comment: after `self.tableview.endUpdates()` add this, `let offset: CGPoint = tableView.contentOffset
        tableView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        tableView.contentOffset = offset`

Comment: I've just tried it, it's still bouncing.

Comment: If I have a few cells, not enough to fill the tableview, it doesn't bounce.

if I have much more cells to scroll the tableview, it doesn't bounce.

However, if I have just enough cells to fill the tableview, this is where it bounces.

Answer (score -1):

On iOS 11 similar issue, replace by [tableView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil]; solve the issue..

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't seem to work. Where exactly do I put performBatchUpdates ?

Answer (score -2):

```
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

Comment: I have recently rephrased this question here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/50981504/1126973

Comment: @nouatzi after any change in cell subviews or resizing cell by collapse and expand

Comment: try to avoid reloadData as long as you only change cell height

Comment: You should really take a look at my recent question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50981504/1126973 the scenario is way more simple. I don’t use reloadData