# UITableView unexpectedly bounces with beginUpdates()/endUpdates()/performBatchUpdates() using NSFetchedResultsController and CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

`UITableView` unexpectedly bounces with `beginUpdates()` / `endUpdates()` / `performBatchUpdates()` using `NSFetchedResultsController` and CoreData when the number of rows fill the view.
It's pretty simple to reproduce.
- Create a new project from the Master-Detail App Template (with CoreData).
- In the storyboard, remove the "showDetail" segue. (we don't need the detail view)
- In MasterViewController, replace segue func `prepare()` with :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {  
    let event = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)  
    let timestamp = event.timestamp  
    event.timestamp = timestamp // The idea is to simply update the Event entity.  
  }
```

Launch the app (in iOS devices or Simulators), and add enough rows to fill the view (in iPhone SE, it 11 rows).
Scroll down the view, and select any row. The view WILL rapidly BOUNCE up and down.
Is that a bug, or is there an issue with the code ?

Comment: So you mean if you comment out statements in `didSelectRowAt` then it wont bounce ? But seems like you have no code associated with beginUpdate() endUpdate() n all in  `didSelectRowAt`

Comment: the `didSelectRowAt` function is not present in the template, I've added it. And yes, it will bounce. The only thing preventing from bouncing is to remove `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` in `controllerWillChangeContent()` and `controllerDidChangeContent()`, but I'll loose their functionalities. Did you tried to reproduce the code ?

Comment: : Havent tried yet, lemme try and get back

Comment: So I guess the thread is dead....

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I might have found a solution, please tell me guys what you think.
The idea would be to process `insert/delete/move` in `performBatchUpdates` and leave `update` out of it.
So I've created this enum and property:

```
enum FetchedResultsChange<Object> {
  case insert(IndexPath)
  case delete(IndexPath)
  case move(IndexPath, IndexPath, Object)
}
var fetchedResultsChanges: [FetchedResultsChange<Event>] = []
```

And `controllerWillChangeContent` becomes empty:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {}
```

`didChange` becomes:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
      self.fetchedResultsChanges.append(.insert(newIndexPath!))
    case .delete:
      self.fetchedResultsChanges.append(.delete(indexPath!))
    case .update:
      configureCell(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!, withEvent: anObject as! Event) // So this stays untouched.
    case .move:
      self.fetchedResultsChanges.append(.move(indexPath!, newIndexPath!, anObject as! Event))
    }
  }
```

And `controllerDidChangeContent` becomes:

```
  func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    guard self.fetchedResultsChanges.count > 0 else { return }

    tableView.performBatchUpdates({
      repeat {
        let change = self.fetchedResultsChanges.removeFirst()
        switch change {
        case .insert(let newIndexPath):
          tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .fade)
        case .delete(let indexPath):
          tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        case .move(let indexPath, let newIndexPath, let event):
          configureCell(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!, withEvent: event)
          tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: newIndexPath)
        }
      } while self.fetchedResultsChanges.count > 0
    }, completion: nil)
  }
```

So what do you think ?

Comment: I'm also having this same issue now argg. Did you ever find a better solution to the above?

Comment: I might have found a solution. Give me 5 min, I'll write you the code.

Comment: check the refined solution above.

Answer (score 1):

A more refined solution is

```swift
  lazy var sectionChanges = [() -> Void]()
  lazy var objectChanges = [() -> Void]()

  func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    guard controller == self._fetchedResultsController else { return }
    self.sectionChanges.removeAll()
    self.objectChanges.removeAll()
  }

  func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    guard controller == self._fetchedResultsController else { return }
    let sections = IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex)
    self.sectionChanges.append { [unowned self] in
      switch type {
      case .insert: self.tableView.insertSections(sections, with: .fade)
      case .delete: self.tableView.deleteSections(sections, with: .fade)
      default: break
      }
    }
  }

  func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    guard controller == self._fetchedResultsController else { return }
    switch type {
    case .insert:
      if let verifiedNewIndexPath = newIndexPath {
        self.objectChanges.append { [unowned self] in
          self.tableView.insertRows(at: [verifiedNewIndexPath], with: .fade)
        }
      }
    case .delete:
      if let verifiedIndexPath = indexPath {
        self.objectChanges.append { [unowned self] in
          self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [verifiedIndexPath], with: .fade)
        }
      }
    case .update:
      if let verifiedIndexPath = indexPath, let event = anObject as? Event, let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: verifiedIndexPath) {
        self.configureCell(cell, withEvent: event)
      }
    case .move:
      if let verifiedIndexPath = indexPath, let verifiedNewIndexPath = newIndexPath, let event = anObject as? Event, let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: verifiedIndexPath) {
        self.configureCell(cell, withEvent: event)
        self.objectChanges.append { [unowned self] in
          self.tableView.moveRow(at: verifiedIndexPath, to: verifiedNewIndexPath)
        }
      }
    default: break
    }
  }

  func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    guard controller == self._fetchedResultsController else { return }
    guard self.objectChanges.count > 0 || self.sectionChanges.count > 0 else { return }
    self.tableView.performBatchUpdates({[weak self] in
      self?.objectChanges.forEach { $0() }
      self?.sectionChanges.forEach { $0() }
    }) { (finished) in
      // here I check if the tableView is empty. If so, I usually add a label saying "no item, click add button to add items."
      // If not, then I remove this label.
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is beautiful! Thanks, you saved me tons of time!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the similar (duplicate?) question at [UITableView unexpectedly bounces with beginUpdates()/endUpdates()/performBatchUpdates()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48658226/uitableview-unexpectedly-bounces-with-beginupdates-endupdates-performbatchup/54963747#54963747)

I added an answer there about using the `estimatedHeightFor...` methods of the table view. Implementing these methods to return a positive number fixes the odd bounce problem during table view batch updates.

Answer (score -2):

This may help -

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                                self.tableView?.beginUpdates()
                                let contentOffset = self.tableView?.contentOffset
                                self.tableView?.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: j, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                                self.tableView?.setContentOffset(contentOffset!, animated: false)
                                self.tableView?.endUpdates()
                            }
```

Comment: Where do I put it ? in `controllerWillChangeContent()` or `controllerDidChangeContent()` ?

Comment: `beginUpdates / endUpdates` has no effect at all in this context. And why is the table view optional?

Comment: do you have any idea vadian ? did you tried to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: @nouatzi No need to reproduce the issue. Begin/end updates is for batch insert/delete operations and this code doesn't even have a single table operation.

Comment: No, I was taking about Xcode template code, with my modification.